# Android : How to stick middle layout on top at the time of scrolling

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, scrollview

When I scroll vertically at that time when middle layout(yellow view) come on top then it should be stick on top position and scroll rest of bottom layout. 
I don't have idea to how to active that Please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewFirst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#990000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewMiddle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ddaa00" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="#0000AA" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably not exactly what you want, however it may help you do what you want to do.

You can use a [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout) that holds `AppBarLayout` & some other scrolling view like in your case a `ScrollView`

- The `AppBarLayout` holds both your `viewFirst` & `viewFirst2`
- `viewFirst` must be wrapped in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` attribute set
- The scrolling view must have `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute set to make the `CoordintatorLayout` functions.

If you're going to use `ScrollView`, then you've to use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` To enable the scrolling behavior of the `CoordintatorLayout` along with the scrolling functionality of the `ScrollView` itself.

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` is only available starting from API-21

Alternatively you can use `NestedScrollView` or any other scrolling view like `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewFirst"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:background="#990000" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewMiddle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ddaa00" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="#0000AA"
            android:text="
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ipsum auctor magna scelerisque. Dignissim ante a, eros vel et donec, eu bibendum in donec diam nec, venenatis quam vel est et lacinia sem, nunc ac qui in eu vel pede. Nec duis, nullam arcu iaculis ligula congue urna in, malesuada lorem mauris, nonummy malesuada diam et congue, laoreet in quis. Arcu suspendisse parturient erat, aliquet aliquam maecenas proin vel faucibus cras, per vestibulum ut id tellus. Ridiculus quis luctus praesent fusce, iaculis amet nunc nisl. Tortor proin curabitur vestibulum, ut mi maecenas nisl diam, ligula amet erat per vel risus, molestie a tempor ut integer, volutpat porttitor lectus adipisicing elit egestas. Tellus ullamcorper fusce nullam donec urna, proin purus est vitae dui suspendisse erat, nullam posuere gravida nibh odio elementum non.

Mi ac proin suspendisse eu, in dui. A maecenas, quam cras dictum lorem libero nibh venenatis. Tristique ac, ligula eget volutpat, nascetur nec. Luctus commodi, mi volutpat ante consectetuer purus dictumst wisi, laoreet ut sem molestie blandit sed. Mollis odio neque, erat et tortor vel nonummy. Morbi luctus eget laoreet tortor vitae ligula, aliquam a nisl amet magna. Pellentesque lorem feugiat pellentesque euismod eget, id vel arcu ipsum morbi, feugiat sed non erat integer, non at proin aenean nunc ultrices, orci eu. Vulputate aliquam rutrum, elit nibh, ac cras ut nisl sed et interdum, gravida suspendisse sed aenean, habitant in lectus sit. Dolor vivamus in a ut, nec adipiscing. Quis consectetuer, accumsan tempor elit fusce sit et.

Feugiat suspendisse cras erat ligula cursus augue, lectus est elementum mauris etiam fermentum ornare. Rhoncus donec blandit fermentum iure elit fusce. Nec ornare. Vestibulum praesent, eget lacinia eget phasellus nullam hendrerit id. Dignissim aliquet, eu per deserunt quam enim adipiscing, urna lacus eros adipiscing, vestibulum eget imperdiet, sagittis lectus lorem lobortis morbi. Eget per enim nulla metus amet nulla. Sit commodo varius sagittis non, sed ipsum, orci eu ut egestas eum suscipit, nulla nullam congue praesent, quis faucibus. Lacus vestibulum ipsum eget lobortis blandit, pellentesque wisi tortor vestibulum tempor laoreet. Augue vivamus in consequat nunc a sem, justo ultricies cras lacinia, dui posuere ultrices facilisis, nibh nunc vel in tempus, ac diam donec sit urna. Sed eleifend hendrerit magna, sed vestibulum nec vivamus massa. Phasellus sodales in ut consequat dictum sapien, eu erat cras tellus. Sed provident, eget aenean, etiam egestas ac sed ac.

Auctor a etiam, ipsum venenatis sociosqu ut elementum sodales et, venenatis a libero porro vehicula. Arcu dictum sed tempor, libero aliquam, aenean viverra congue eros sed. Etiam aenean eleifend sit mauris, wisi pellentesque massa non urna suscipit. Nisl sit euismod cursus lectus. Lacus ligula ipsum quam dui curabitur eros. At aliquam torquent varius proin sociosqu, mi id fringilla nec."
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </ScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Preview

[image]

You can also have a look at [this library](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) as alternative solution.